# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show Couldn't find Article without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I am trying to submit some data to db and its ok but when i am trying to retrieve those data show that Couldn't find Article without an ID.ils 4.0.1.
I am using ruby 2.0.0 and ra

```
def show
@article=Article.find(params[:id])
```

end

```
the ** contain error. 

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  redirect_to @article
  @article.save
  end

 def show
  @article=Article.find(params[:id])
  end
  private
   def article_params

   params.require(:article).permit(:title, :full_name, :email, :phone_number, :message)
  end

   end
```

articles/show.html.erb

```
<p>
 <strong>Title:</strong>
 <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
 <strong>Full Name:</strong>
 <%= @article.full_name %>
 </p>

 <p>
 <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @article.email %>
  </p>

 <p>
  <strong>Phone Number:</strong>
   <%= @article.phone_number %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <strong>Message:</strong>
   <%= @article.message %>
   </p>
```

articles/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Articles</h1>

 <%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
   <%= f.label :title %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :full_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :full_name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.label :email %>
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
   <p>
   <%= f.label :phone_number %>
   <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
   </p>
   <%= f.label :message %>
   <%= f.text_field :message %>
   <p>
    <%= f.submit :send_message %>
    </p>

   <% end %>
```

Comment: when i press save button its show again redirect error.

Comment: NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create                                              undefined method `article_url' for #<ArticlesController:                                                       @article =Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end again after refresh ActionController::ParameterMissing in ArticlesController#show             param not found: article                                                                            private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :full_name, :email, :phone_number, :message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting before actually saving your article.

This:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  redirect_to @article
  @article.save
end
```

should be:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  @article.save
  redirect_to @article      
end
```

And if you want to add some error handling as well:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render :new
end
```